# WHERE IN en php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo este código en mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `dev_transacciones` 
WHERE `id_transaccion` IN (SELECT MAX(`id_transaccion`) 
                           FROM `dev_transacciones` 
                           GROUP BY `id_producto`)
                           ORDER BY `id_transaccion` DESC
```

esto muestra una tabla que muestra el ultimo id_transaccion y los agrupa de manera descendiente por id_producto

Y tengo este código en php

```
  $data['inventario'] = $this->transaccionesModel
   ->select('dev_transacciones.*')
   ->where('id_transaccion', 'IN (SELECT MAX(id_transaccion)')
   ->groupBy('dev_transacciones.id_producto')
   ->orderBy('dev_transacciones.id_transaccion desc')
   ->findAll();
```

Cuando utilizo `print($data['inventario'])` muestra un array vació

**Mi duda es como hacer la consulta de SQL en PHP, ya que el código de php muestra un Array vació, no lo muestra como la segunda imagen que agregue**

La primera imagen es la tabla normal y la segunda es con la consulta sql

[image: La tabla normal sin where in es]

[image: La tabla con la consulta sql es asi]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes? En tu pregunta no veo que preguntes alguna duda. Corrige eso para que tu pregunta no sea eliminada.

Comment: @AarónRojas perdon, ahora edito la pregunta, mi duda es como hacer la consulta de SQL en PHP, ya que el código de php muestra un Array vació, no lo muestra como la segunda imagen que mande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, tenia que quedar así

```
$data['inventario'] = $this->transaccionesModel
   ->select('dev_transacciones.*')
   ->where('dev_transacciones.id_transaccion IN (SELECT MAX(`id_transaccion`)
   FROM `dev_transacciones`
   GROUP BY `id_producto`)')

   ->orderBy('dev_transacciones.id_transaccion desc')
```

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, te recomiendo modificarla, si no podría ser eliminada